# $(a, b) = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\right\}$ has neither minimum nor maximum.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

How does one prove that $(a, b) = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\right\}$ has neither minimum nor maximum?

My attempt: Suppose that $\mu$ is the minimum of the set. Then $a < \mu < x < b$, since $a$ does not belong to the set. Which contradicts the minimality of $\mu$. Does this make any sense?

Comment: No. However, since you have $\mu >a$ then $\mu > {1 \over 2} (a+ \mu) > a$ which contradicts $\mu$ being a minimum.

Comment: Nothing was said about minimality of $a$, it is $\mu$ that is minimal.

Comment: Suppose $\mu$ is the minimum, then $a < \dfrac{a + \mu}{2} < \mu$, wich contradicts our assumption that $\mu$ is the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not good. Suppose $\mu$ is the minimum of $(a,b)$. Then look at the element $(a+\mu)/2$. Check that this element is in $(a,b)$, and that it is less than $\mu$. This contradicts the minimality of $\mu$. Try to copy this reasoning for proving that $(a,b)$ doesn't have a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to approach this is to reason by way of contradiction.  Here is a more formalized explanation of the hint Ivo Terek supplied.  Suppose there exists an $m \in (a,b)$ such that for all $x \in (a,b)$, $m \le x$.  Then, as suggested, construct $m^* = (m + a)/2$.  Verify that $m^* \in (a,b)$, because $m^* > a$ and $m^* < b$.  Then verify that $m^* < m$, because $m > a$.  But this contradicts the presumption that $m \le x$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, since we found $m^* \in (a,b)$ such that $m^* < m$; therefore, no such $m$ can exist.